# Ruby headscratcher - instance variable isn't outputted

Tags: ruby, syntax, instance-variables

I'm probably doing something stupid but I can't figure out what it is.

The output I'm seeing from this program is

```
foo

test
```

What I'm expecting to see is

```
foo
abc
test
```

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here?

```
class Foo

    def initialize(l)
    @label = l
    end

    def label
    @label
    end

    def abc
    @abc
    end

    def abc=(abc)
    @abc
    end

end

foo = Foo.new("foo")
foo.abc=("abc")
puts foo.label
puts foo.abc
puts "test"
```

Comment: Nice, always learn to double check for stupidity. :) I've done this before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never set @abc in your `abc=` method. It should look like

```
def abc=(val)
  @abc = val
end
```

Comment: Damn. I knew it was going to be something stupid. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Logan's answer which tells you what the error was, here's how that error never would have occurred in the first place:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(l)
    @label = l
  end

  attr_reader :label
  attr_accessor :abc
end
```